# Ledmac - suppresing bold in lemma note

Tags: formatting, footnotes, bold, ledmac

I am typesetting my thesis, an edition of a Latin text with Spanish translation. Bible quotations in the main text are in bold letters. However, when I make a lemma footnote I do not want the bold font to pass to the notes. 
I found this trick [from Dirk-Jan Dekker](http://www.djdekker.net/ledmac/#lfont)

```
\makeatletter
\def\select@lemmafont#1|#2|#3|#4|#5|#6|#7|%
  {\select@@lemmafont#7|}
\def\select@@lemmafont#1/#2/#3/#4|%
  {\fontencoding{#1}\fontfamily{#2}\fontshape{#4}%
  \selectfont}
\makeatother
```

But I do not know where in my preamble I should place it. I have tried several places and when I compile the application seems to get into a loop and it simply goes on and on.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Can you add a minimal document that shows the undesirable behaviour that you're observing? That'll give us something to play with.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to get so complicated.  Look at this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ledmac}                                               
\let\appcrit\Afootnote% <-- apparatus criticus
\footparagraph{A} 
% now three commands, one normal, one with unique \lemma, one without unique lemma
\newcommand{\apc}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\appcrit{#2}}}%
\newcommand{\apcl}[3]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\appcrit{#3}}}%
\newcommand{\nobold}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{\textnormal{#1}}\appcrit{#2}}}%                                     
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\beginnumbering
\pstart 
I am typesetting my thesis, an edition of a Latin text with Spanish
translation. \apc{\textbf{Bible quotations}}{this one has a bold lemma} in 
the main text are in bold letters. However, when I make a lemma footnote I 
\apcl{do not want the bold}{do not want the bold}{so no bold} font to pass 
to the notes. I found this trick from Dirk-Jan Dekker.  But I do not know 
where in my preamble I should place it. I have tried several places and 
when I compile the application seems to get into a loop and it simply goes 
on and on. \nobold{Can anybody help me with this}{no bold, but without 
unique lemmata}?
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```